# How to call and get API responses from middle proxy?

Tags: php, json, api

[image]

Refer to attached image. I'm making an interface for user to make input on 123.com and will pass value to middle server (abc.com) then abc.com will pass value and parameter to API provider server (xyz.com).

I'm wonder after API provider (xyz.com) response back to middle server (abc.com), how I can deliver API responses back to user via 123.com?

Thank you for your suggestion.
Tung

Answer (score 1):

- 123.com - jQuery Ajax request to ABC.com based on form inputs.
- ABC.com - php receives Ajax request and hits XYZ.com API via curl
- XYZ.com - API responds to ABC.com
- ABC.com - Parses the response and produces a response back to 123.com

Comment: Thank you ChrisFNZ, I will try your solution.